# How would I tar extract pipe cd?

Tags: shell, pipe

So I found out that I could pipe the following two commands:

```sh
sudo wget https://example.com/folder.tar.gz
sudo tar xzvf folder.tar.gz
```

like this:

```sh
sudo wget -q http://example.com/folder.tar.gz -O - | tar xzvf -
```

So now I was wondering how I could *also* `cd` into this folder.

I guessed:

```sh
sudo wget -q http://example.com/folder.tar.gz -O - | tar xzvf - | cd
# and
sudo wget -q http://example.com/folder.tar.gz -O - | tar xzvf - | cd -
```

but these two are not working. I'm very sure that I'm not understanding pipes very well.

Comment: Pipes link up the output of one program to the input of another - just how a pipe sends the output from your garden tap (faucet) to your lawn sprinkler. A minus sign (`-`) is a shortcut meaning either `input` or `output` - which one it means depends on position/context.

Comment: @MarkSetchell does that mean that the second thing I tried should be working?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pipes link up the output of one program to the input of another - just how a pipe sends the output from your garden tap (faucet) to your lawn sprinkler.

A minus sign (-) is a shortcut meaning either input or output - which one it means depends on position/context.

Your `wget` command grabs some data from the web and, because of the `-`, sends it through a pipe to `tar`.

The `tar` command reads that data from the pipe, because of its `-`, and creates some files and directories.

The `tar` command doesn't send anything down any further pipes, so there'd be nothing for `cd` to read. You also don't know the name of the directory you want to go to. If you did, you could go there as a follow-up action like this:

```
wget ... - | tar ... - ; cd SOMEWHERE
```

Or you could make it conditional on the `tar` command running successfully with:

```
wget ... - | tar ... - && cd SOMEWHERE
```

Comment: So if I wanted to make a shell script to do this for me, then I would have to save the output of `wget` in a variable, *then* pass it to `tar` and `cd`?

Comment: When you run a script, it starts a new process. That process would grab the file from the web, untar its contents, change directory and then exit. The new process exits. It disappears. It doesn't matter what directory it went to because that will not affect the shell that started the script... because it is a separate, distinct process.

Comment: Maybe you could be more explicit about what you want to do. What if the tar archive you download has 5 directories in it - where do you want to go then? What are you going to do when you get there?

Comment: I wanted to extract to a folder and then `cd` into that folder. It was just a matter of seeing if I could do it in a single line, or if I would have to make a script with some outside logic for it. Thank you for your help, I've learned a good lesson :3